# How to use tensorflow-lite.lib？

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite

When I followed the tutorial on the [official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#release_build).
I successfully compiled the library file “tensorflow-lite.lib”，It's about 200M，but i can't use it correctly.
My cmakelist is like this：

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(minimal C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

link_directories(./libs/windows)

add_executable(minimal minimal.cc)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(minimal tensorflow-lite)
```

When I wanted to use this library, a series of errors occurred:

```
tensorflow-lite.lib(interpreter.cc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl ruy::ScopedSuppressDenormals::ScopedSuppressDenormals(void)" (??0ScopedSuppressDenormals@ruy@@QEAA@XZ), function The symbol is referenced in "public: enum TfLiteStatus __cdecl tflite::impl::Interpreter::Invoke(void)" (?Invoke@Interpreter@impl@tflite@@QEAA?AW4TfLiteStatus@@XZ)
tensorflow-lite.lib(interpreter.cc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl ruy::ScopedSuppressDenormals::~ScopedSuppressDenormals(void)" (??1ScopedSuppressDenormals@ruy@@QEAA@XZ), The symbol is referenced in the function "public: enum TfLiteStatus __cdecl tflite::impl::Interpreter::Invoke(void)" (?Invoke@Interpreter@impl@tflite@@QEAA?AW4TfLiteStatus@@XZ)
tensorflow-lite.lib(fully_connected.cc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ruy::Ctx * __cdecl ruy::get_ctx(class ruy::Context *)" (?get_ctx@ruy@@YAPEAVCtx @1@PEAVContext@1@@Z)
tensorflow-lite.lib(lstm.cc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ruy::Ctx * __cdecl ruy::get_ctx(class ruy::Context *)" (?get_ctx@ruy@@YAPEAVCtx @1@PEAVContext@1@@Z)
tensorflow-lite.lib(transpose_conv.cc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ruy::Ctx * __cdecl ruy::get_ctx(class ruy::Context *)" (?get_ctx@ruy@@YAPEAVCtx @1@PEAVContext@1@@Z)...
```

This seems to be due to the fact that the static library of tensorflow-lite.lib has other dependencies (I am not sure
), so how can I correctly configure other dependencies of this library in other projects.

How should I configure other dependent libraries? Its cmakelist for tensorflow-lite.lib is so complex that I can't figure out which ones it needs. And why it has more than 200 m (isn't it because tflite packages all its dependent libraries？)